# Can I call a div inside another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a div component that is very large.

```
<div id='download>
.....
</div>
```

I want to use this same component inside a Paper in a Modal.

```
<Modal>
          <Box sx={style} >
            <Paper elevation={0}>
            <Typography id="transition-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
              Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
            </Typography>
            </Paper>
          </Box>
</Modal>
```

I could paste the entire div but that would slow down the application and is not very efficient.
Both these components are in the same file so I thought I'd use getElementById, but I am not sure that's the right way to go about it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Turn your div into a component and use it.

Comment: Also remove the `id` attribute if you use it more than once in a view. [IDs must be unique in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you can turn your div into a component and use it within the `<Modal />`

```
const LargeDiv = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>

function Page() {
return (
  <Modal>
    <Box>
      <LargeDiv />
      ...
    </Box>
  </Modal>
)
}
```